# Unable to create a SnapShot in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, snapshot-isolation

Any ideas why this would be happening? Corrupt directory perhaps?  I did a lot of copying back and forth with these files.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a really strange XCode issue, but I believe you can resolve it by deleting the `.DS_Store` file it complains about. (`.DS_Store` files are something like Finder image caches and can be safely removed)

The `.DS_Store` files are hidden by default, so the easiest way to remove them is using the Terminal, `rm <path to file>`, you can use `TAB` key to autocomplete path.

Comment: That did it. There were a few in various dirs that I ended up removing. Thanks!